# julia language Triangular distribution parameterization

Tags: distribution, julia, triangular

Julia seems to be parameterizing the triangular distributions using location and scale parameters only.  How does this translate to the location, shape, scale parameterization. for example suppose that `Z` has the basic triangle distribution with vertex at `p ∈ [0,1]`. For `a ∈ R` and `w ∈ (0,∞), X=a+wZ` has the triangle distribution with location parameter `a`, and scale parameter `w`, and shape parameter `p`.

Answer (score 1):

We implemented the two-parameter Triangular distribution that is defined in this document: http://www.stat.rice.edu/~dobelman/textfiles/DistributionsHandbook.pdf

If you'd be interested in implementing the generalization of that distribution with three parameters (as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution), that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

[`TriangularDist`](http://distributionsjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate-continuous.html#TriangularDist) has been changed since this was asked: it takes 3-parameters: minimum, mode, and maximum.